# AIR for iOS - Unable to play F4V video with StageVideo

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to play a F4V video with H264 encoding using StageVideo on AIR for iOS (iPad).
I'm using F4V because I need cuePoints in the video.

My video player works when using MP4 instead of F4V.
Is there a solution to play F4V in AIR for iOS through StageVideo? Or a way to embed cuePoints metadata in an MP4 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not found any solutions to make it work.

So, i've ended up with a solution which play MP4 (H264) video and loading a text file filled with cuepoints informations (JSON loaded via URLLoader).

Then, i'm parsing the text file and handle CuePoints manually.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link -> [Adobe AIR 3.7  -  Bug 3558253](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3558253) 

There is however a working example for local files as .zip for H264